# iOS ObjectMapper incremental updating

Tags: ios, swift, objectmapper

I have a problem with my project, when my App starts, the configuration is automatically updated from the server, the json from server like this:

```
{
"version":1 
"config": 
{
    "key1": {xxx}
    "key2": {xxx}
    "key3": {xxx}
    "key4": {xxx}
    "key5": {xxx}
    "key6": {xxx}
}
```

And I use the `ObjectMapper` to convert json to model, like this:

```
struct GlobalConfig: Mappable {

var version = 0
var key1: [String: [LocalizedText]]?
var key2: [RouteObject]?
var key3: UrlConfig?
var key4: [String: [String: [[String: Any]]]]?
var key5: DegreeInfoList?
var key6: [String: String]?

init?(map: Map) { }

mutating func mapping(map: Map) {
    version <- map["version"]
    key1 <- map["key1"]
    key2 <- map["key2"]
    key3 <- map["key3"]
    key4 <- map["key4"]
    key5 <- map["key5"]
    key6 <- map["key6"]
}
```

Now there is a problem, when the json from server is large, it will consume a lot of traffic. In fact, some configurations do not need to be updated. So the json from server will like this:

```
{
"version":2
"config": 
{
    "key1": {xxx}
    "key2": {xxx}
}
```

It means `key1` and `key2` will be updated, `key3`, `key4`, `key5` and `key6` keep the old values.
**How to handle the JSON?**

Comment: In this case I would use traditional `JSONSerialization` because you are able to enumerate the data and update the existing model.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't understand what's the `Mapper` object is. It can be done with `Codable`.

You can do like this to update your local config with incoming config.

```swift
struct GlobalConfig: Codable {
    var version = 0
    var key1: [String: [LocalizedText]]?
    var key2: [RouteObject]?
    var key3: UrlConfig?
    var key4: [String: [String: [[String: Any]]]]?
    var key5: DegreeInfoList?
    var key6: [String: String]?
    
    mutating func combine(with config: GlobalConfig) {
        if let k = config.key1 { key1 = k }
        if let k = config.key2 { key2 = k }
        ...
    }
}

class App {
    var config: GlobalConfig
    
    func receiveConfig(newConfig: GlobalConfig) {
        config.combine(with: newConfig)
    }
}
```

**Edited :**

In response to comment, here a possible solution for 'deep' combine.

Very roughly :

```swift
extension Dictionary {
    func combine(with dictionary: Dictionary) {

    } 
}

extension Array {
    func combine(with array: Array) {

    } 
}

protocol Combinable: Codable {
    func combine(with object: Self)
}

struct GlobalConfig: Combinable {
    var version = 0
    var key1: [String: [LocalizedText]]?
    var key2: [RouteObject]?

    mutating func combine(with config: GlobalConfig) {
        if let k = config.key1 { key1.combine(with: k) }
        if let k = config.key2 { key2.combine(with: k) }
        ...
    }
}
```

This is another subject, but types like `[String: [String: [[String: Any]]]]` should be avoided.
It is hard to read, debug, and combine ;)

I think it is better to use structured sub-models. Much safer, scalable and 'documentable'.

```swift
struct GlobalConfig: Codable {
    ...
    // Old format: var key4: [String: [String: [[String: Any]]]]?
    var key4: MegaSettings?
    ...
}

struct MegaSettings: Combinable {
    struct ScreenOptions: Combinable {
        var options: [String: Any]
    }

    struct DisplayOptions: Combinable {
        struct DeviceDisplayOptions {
            var screen: [ScreenOptions]
        }

        var optionsPerDevice: [String: DeviceDisplayOptions]
    }

    var displayOptions: [String: DisplayOptions]
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your solution, It is a good ideal for simple JSON. But when the JSON like this:`{
"version":1 
"config": 
{
    "key1": {
          "desc1": "xxx"
          "desc2": "xxx"
     }
}`
update:
`{
"version":2 
"config": 
{
    "key1": {
          "desc1": "yyy"
     }
}`
The desc2 will lose.

Comment: Took your comment in account ;)

Comment: This method works and I will use it.
Thank you 